# Python3.4 -Nmap Requires root privileges

Tags: python-3.x, privileges, nmap

Running on Mac Os 10.10.5
Running this script to scan for hosts on the network:

```
import nmap
nm = nmap.PortScanner()
nm.scan('192.168.5.1/24', arguments='-O')
for h in nm.all_hosts():
    if 'mac' in nm[h]['addresses']:
        print(nm[h]['addresses'], nm[h]['vendor'])
```

When running it its printing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/nmap/nmap.py", line 290, in analyse_nmap_xml_scan
    dom = ET.fromstring(self._nmap_last_output)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1326, in XML
    return parser.close()
  File "<string>", line None
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: no element found: line 1, column 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/*/Documents/*.py", line 3, in <module>
    nm.scan('192.168.0.0/24', arguments='-O')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/nmap/nmap.py", line 235, in scan
    nmap_err_keep_trace = nmap_err_keep_trace)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/nmap/nmap.py", line 293, in analyse_nmap_xml_scan
    raise PortScannerError(nmap_err)
nmap.nmap.PortScannerError: 'TCP/IP fingerprinting (for OS scan) requires root privileges.\nQUITTING!\n'
```

I tried going to that directory and running this command in the terminal:
sudo python *.py

```
({'mac': '02:62:31:41:6D:84', 'ipv4': '192.168.5.1'}, {})
```

Any suggestions to run the script from the python IDLE?

Comment: @IanAuld Mac OS 10.10.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running IDLE as root might work, but it might not be a great idea.  `sudo idle`

**Option 1 (recommended):**

Put the code requiring elevated privileges in a python file which you run with sudo.  I assume you want to play with the results, so you could have the script save the results to a file, which you then read in IDLE.

The following code works in python 2.7 and 3.4

```
import nmap
import json

nm = nmap.PortScanner()
nm.scan('192.168.5.1/24',arguments='-O') #Note that I tested with -sP to save time
output = []
with open('output.txt', 'a') as outfile:
  for h in nm.all_hosts():
    if 'mac' in nm[h]['addresses']:
      item = nm[h]['addresses']
      if nm[h]['vendor'].values():
        item['vendor'] = list(nm[h]['vendor'].values())[0]
      output.append(item)
  json.dump(output, outfile)
```

Run `sudo python nmaproot.py`
Since the file is written by root, you need to change ownership back to yourself.
`sudo chown -r myusername output.txt`

In IDLE:

```
import json
input = open('output.txt','r'):
json_data = json.load(input)
json_data[0] # first host
```

**Option 2 (not recommended at all):**

Use subprocess to run the file with the elevated code as root and return the output.  It gets kind of messy and requires you to hardcode your password...but it's possible.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
cmd = ['sudo', '-S', 'python', 'nmaproot.py']
sudopass = 'mypassword'
p = Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE,universal_newlines=True, stdout=PIPE)
output = p.communicate(sudopass + '\n')
```

I'm unsure of how you can run a given portion of your python code as root without saving it to a file and running it separately.  I recommend you go with option 1 as option 2 isn't very good (but it was fun to figure out).

Comment: can you elaborate on how you do option one? I am not sure what you mean by that and how to do it

Comment: Updated the answer with some code on how you might do option 1

Comment: Note, I do not want to have to run it on the terminal.. I would like to do be able to run it on the IDLE if possible

Comment: Your only option is to run IDLE as root then.  `sudo idle` in terminal.  It's a bad security practice though so do so at your own risk.

Comment: Why is it a risk, if I only scan with nmap, there shouldn't be any risks right? And so I would have to run the option 2: Place that code before my code and run it? (tho I understand what it does...)

Comment: If you run idle as root you could do everything in idle without option 1 or 2 (just do what you were doing before).  It's a bad security practice because all of the code you write has root privileges. Be careful what you put in there.  You can find a lot more information about why running arbitrary code as root is a bad practice on the web.  There's no problem with running the given code as root- but all other code you write will also be executed as root, which is where the problem lies.

Comment: I will accept your answer in a sec, is it normal that in the terminal I cannot run : sudo python myfile.py ... I have to go to the directory first with : cd mylocation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88045/discussion-between-duplexia-and-bob).

Answer (score 1):

maybe this might help someone here.  Found this from one site

scanner.scan(ip_addr, '1-1024', '-v -sS', sudo=True)

use

```
sudo = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy the idle desktop shortcut and name it rootidle then right and change properties. Goto desktop entry and add gksu before /usr/bin/idle3. Then load and run the program